# App crash because empty Int value in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing this app that the user needs to pass two `Int` values and the app is crashing when the button is pressed and no values were entered.
How can I solve this issue?
I think it have something to do with the optional values.

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var age_1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var age_2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emoji_button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var date_textField: UILabel!

    let colorProvider = BackgroundColorProvider()

    @IBAction func button_pressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Compare 2 given ages(int) and tell if people can date.
        let me_age =  Int(age_1.text!)!
        let other_age = Int(age_2.text!)!
        let me_age_min  = (me_age / 2) + 7
        let me_age_max = (me_age - 7) * 2

        if me_age == 0 || other_age == 0 {
            date_textField.text = "Enter ages then touch the heart"
        }else if me_age > 18 && other_age < 18{
            date_textField.text = "Don't date an under-age."
        }// Case 2: Person is older and cant´date younger:
        else if me_age < 18 && other_age > 18{
            date_textField.text = "You are under age."
        }else if me_age == other_age{
            date_textField.text = "You definetly should date."
        }else if other_age < me_age_min {
            print (me_age_min)
            date_textField.text = "To young 4 U"
        } // Case 3: Person is young and can't date older:
        else if other_age > me_age_max {
            print ((me_age - 7) * 2 )
            date_textField.text = "To old 4 U"
        } // Case 4: Both people are the same age:
           else{
            date_textField.text = "Yes, you can date. "
        }
```

Comment: which line code make your app crash ?

Comment: thanks a lot: `if me_age == 0 || other_age == 0 {
            date_textField.text = "Enter ages then touch the heart"
    } `

Comment: if there is no text in the `textField`, do you want to get `0` ?

Comment: No. Actually if there's no value in `textField`I want to prompt the user a message asking to enter values. Regards.

Comment: Every use of `!` means "crash here". Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If `Int(someStr)` there will get a `nil`, no matter the string is `""` or some other, so you can not `nil!`, you can judge if the `textField.text` is empty before you get the `int` `value`.

Replace there two line:

```
let me_age =  Int(age_1.text!)!
let other_age = Int(age_2.text!)!
```

To:

```
    var me_age:Int
    if let age1 = Int(age_1.text!) {


        me_age = age1

    }else {

        // there alert to ask user type in age_1
        print("ask user to type in current age_1 ")
        return
    }

    var other_age:Int
    if let age2 = Int(age_2.text!) {


        other_age = age2

    }else {

        // there alert to ask user type in age_1
        print("ask user to type in current age_2")
        return
    }
```

Firstly, if you want to type in `age` in your `textField`, you should set the `textField`'s `keyboard` type to `Number Pad`.

Comment: You should also explain why this will work instead of just typing the code.

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier "me_age". I think I need to first declare a var me_age right?

Comment: Your code would crash if user input some text which cannot be converted to `Int`, it is not clearly stated in the question or the comments, but crashing is something you should always avoid.

Comment: Your updated code still has chance to crash. `age_1.text` and `age_2.text` (your second `age_1.text` should be `age_2.text`) can be `nil`. Simply, remove all forced unwrapping (`!`) to avoid unintended crash.

Comment: @OOPer age1.text default is "", and why remove (`!`) ?   `Int(value)` , the `value` must be a non-option value

Comment: @aircraft, no. The `text` property of `UITextField` can be `nil`. Your assumption _the `value` must be a non-option_ is wrong.

Comment: @OOPer  You is preciseness， it is a good thing to think about that, but you should see this:`@IBOutlet var age_1: UITextField!` his `textField` is create by `storyboard`, it created by `IB`, so we should't consider your case.

Comment: @aircraft, and my words `removing` was also wrong. I meant replacing `!` with something safe.

Comment: @aircraft, I posted an alternative. I am not saying you need to handle the case of `age_1` or `age_2` being `nil`. I say `age_1.text` or `age_2.text` can be `nil`.

Comment: @aircraft, I have found one thing I need to apologize, _age1.text default is ""_ It's true, the default value of `text` property is `""`, and I was misinterpreting your _`Int(value)` , the `value` must be a non-option value_, it's not your assumption, but explaining the requirement for the initializer of `Int`. But, all such things included, my recommendation is still the same, avoid using forced unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write these two lines:

```
let me_age =  Int(age_1.text!)!
let other_age = Int(age_2.text!)!
```

with:

```
guard let me_age = Int(age_1.text ?? "") else {
    date_textField.text = "Enter valid number into age1" //Replace this line to any code you prefer
    return
}
guard let other_age = Int(age_2.text ?? "") else {
    date_textField.text = "Enter valid number into age2" //As well as the line above
    return
}
```

1. If `age_1.text` is `nil`, `age_1.text!` would crash.
2. If `age_1.text!` is not a valid integer, `Int(age_1.text!)!` would crash.
3. If `age_2.text` is `nil`, `age_2.text!` would crash.
4. If `age_2.text!` is not a valid integer, `Int(age_2.text!)!` would crash.

So, people call `!` as a *crash me* operator, you'd better avoid using it if you do not want to crash your app.

(Semantically `age_1` or `age_2` can be `nil`, but if you connect `@IBOutlet` properly that cannot be an issue.)